# Select specif row data (numeric) from list of 5 (dimnames) in a $ : chr row in multiple tables

Tags: r, dataframe

Hy everybody. I'm kind of stuck with simple code. In fact I have this output:

```
roc_value

, , MAXENT.Phillips, RUN1, PA1

         Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
KAPPA           0.558  484.0      63.713      90.667
TSS             0.555  354.0      73.840      81.667
ROC             0.863  369.5      72.996      83.000
ACCURACY        0.788  484.0      63.713      90.667
BIAS            0.996  344.0      73.840      79.667

, , GLM, RUN1, PA1

         Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
KAPPA           0.565    422      83.122      74.333
TSS             0.575    422      83.122      74.333
ROC             0.843    420      83.122      74.333
ACCURACY        0.782    422      83.122      74.333
BIAS            0.979    518      72.574      79.667

, , GAM, RUN1, PA1

         Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
KAPPA           0.664  554.0      81.435      85.000
TSS             0.664  554.0      81.435      85.000
ROC             0.885  557.5      81.435      85.333
ACCURACY        0.834  595.0      76.793      88.667
BIAS            0.996  554.0      81.435      85.000

, , RF, RUN1, PA1

         Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
KAPPA           0.768    404      83.544      92.000
TSS             0.762    404      83.544      92.000
ROC             0.950    406      83.544      92.667
ACCURACY        0.886    485      81.435      94.333
BIAS            0.987    343      84.810      89.000

, , MAXENT.Tsuruoka, RUN1, PA1

         Testing.data Cutoff Sensitivity Specificity
KAPPA           0.509    368      86.498      66.000
TSS             0.527    321      90.717      61.667
ROC             0.838    372      86.498      66.333
ACCURACY        0.756    479      74.262      76.333
BIAS            0.970    488      70.464      78.667
```

the str(roc_value) is:

```
num [1:5, 1:4, 1:5, 1, 1] 0.558 0.555 0.863 0.788 0.996 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 5
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "KAPPA" "TSS" "ROC" "ACCURACY" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "Testing.data" "Cutoff" "Sensitivity" "Specificity"
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "MAXENT.Phillips" "GLM" "GAM" "RF" ...
  ..$ : chr "RUN1"
  ..$ : Named chr "PA1"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr ""
```

I want to select only ROC values from Testing.data column in a single object (to continue my script), for instance:

```
whatidlike <- c(0.863,0.843,0.885,0.950,0.838) # only a single object with ROC values.
```

Tried `dplyr`, `subset` etc. and can't move on. Could someone, please, give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

You list object names look strange `', , RF, RUN1, PA1'` but you should be able to access them using index. e.g. roc_value[[1]], roc_value[[2]]... etc

so, then further to select Testing.data would be simply as 
`roc_value[[1]]['Testing.data']`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Steve.